# Converting array data into a table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with three object in it. I want to map all of them and render them in a table in react. I am able to extract values using map method, bu I am not sure how to render them as a table.

```js
[
   {
      "email":"gowtham@outlook.com",
      "firstname":"gowtham",
      "lastname":"ss",
      "password":"outlook010"
   },
   {
      "email":"ss@ss.com",
      "firstname":"ss",
      "lastname":"ss",
      "password":"ss"
   },
   {
      "email":"gow@gow.com",
      "firstname":"gow",
      "lastname":"gow",
      "password":"gow"
   }
]
```

[image from chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON8Rn.png)

Following is the code I used to map the array data:

```
const exportHeaderData = Object.values(this.state.registeredData).map(
            (data) => {
                return Object.entries(data).map((key,value) => {
                    return `${key}: ${value}`;
                });
            }
        );
```

I want to render it using a table in react.

Comment: which library are you using for table?

Answer (score 11):

You can do it like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {arrayWithData.map(item => {
      return (
        <tr key={item.password}>
          <td>{ item.firstname }</td>
          <td>{ item.lastname }</td>
          <td>{ item.password }</td>
          <td>{ item.email }</td>
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create components to achieve this like:

- `App` <sub>*Parent component*</sub>

  - `Table` <sub>*Child component*</sub>

    - `TableHeaderRow`  <sub>*Sub-Child component*</sub>
    - `TableRow` <sub>*Sub-Child component*</sub>

```js
const obj = [{email:"gowtham@outlook.com",firstname:"gowtham",lastname:"ss",password:"outlook010"},{email:"ss@ss.com",firstname:"ss",lastname:"ss",password:"ss"},{email:"gow@gow.com",firstname:"gow",lastname:"gow",password:"gow"}];

const TableHeaderRow = () => {
  return <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Password</th></tr>;
}

const TableRow = ({data}) => {
  return data.map((data) =>
    <tr>
      <td>{data.firstname}</td><td>{data.lastname}</td><td>{data.email}</td><td>{data.password}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

const Table = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <TableHeaderRow />
      <TableRow data={data} />
    </table>
  );
}

const App = () => <Table data={obj} />;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
table th {
  padding: 12px 8px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #336699;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one implementation

```js
const Table = () => {
  const data = [
     {
        "email":"gowtham@outlook.com",
        "firstname":"gowtham",
        "lastname":"ss",
        "password":"outlook010"
     },
     {
        "email":"ss@ss.com",
        "firstname":"ss",
        "lastname":"ss",
        "password":"ss"
     },
     {
        "email":"gow@gow.com",
        "firstname":"gow",
        "lastname":"gow",
        "password":"gow"
     }
  ];
  
  return (
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
    {data.map(d => (
      <tr>
        <td>{d.email}</td>
        <td>{d.firstname}</td>
        <td>{d.lastname}</td>
        <td>{d.password}</td>
      </tr>
      )}
  </table>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use map to iterate through the entries and return an HTML Table Row for each entry

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <th>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Password</td>
      </th>
    {this.state.registeredData.map(row => (
      <tr key={row.email}>
        <td>{row.email}</td>
        <td>{row.firstname}</td>
        <td>{row.lastname}</td>
        <td>{row.password}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it like this

```
data=> {
    return(
     <>
     <thead>
     <th>email</th>
     <th> fName </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {this.state.registeredData.map((data) => {
       return (<tr>
       <td>data.email</td>
       <td>data.firstName</td> 
      </tr>)

    });
    }
    </tbody>
     </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
<Tabulate arr={array_of_objects}/>
```

Simple component

```
const Tabulate = ( {arr} ) => {
    const cols = Object.keys(arr[0])

    const header = () => {
        return cols.map(e => <th key={e} align="right">{e}</th>)
    }

    return (
        <table className="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>{header()}</tr>
                {arr.map(row => 
                    <tr>
                        {cols.map(col => <td key={col} align="right">{row[col]}</td>)}
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through your data array into table structure.

```js
const data = [
  {
    email: "gowtham@outlook.com",
    firstname: "gowtham",
    lastname: "ss",
    password: "outlook010",
  },
  {
    email: "ss@ss.com",
    firstname: "ss",
    lastname: "ss",
    password: "ss",
  },
  {
    email: "gow@gow.com",
    firstname: "gow",
    lastname: "gow",
    password: "gow",
  },
];

const Table = () => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((d) => (
        <tr key={d.email}>
          <td>{d.firstname}</td>
          <td>{d.lastname}</td>
          <td>{d.email}</td>
          <td>{d.password}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100530/converting-array-data-into-a-table-in-react#
```